# --incremental lastmodified option for hive imports is not supported

Tags: hive, hql, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

using Sqoop 1.4.7.3.0.1.0-187

```
    sqoop job -D sqoop.metastore.client.record.password=true -D sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect=true \
  --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://${server}:${port}/sqoop \
  --create $sqoopJobName \
  -- import --null-string "null" --null-non-string "null" --mysql-delimiters --hive-drop-import-delims \
  --query "select * from ${sqlTableName} where \$CONDITIONS" \
  --incremental lastmodified \
  --last-value '2020-01-16 15:25:16'\
  --check-column UpdateDate \
  -m 4 --split-by $columnId \
  --target-dir hdfs://HDP//input/sqoopimport_action_workflow/$targetDirectoryName/ \
  --hive-import --hive-table $tableNameForHive \
  --connect $connectionString \
  --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver  \
  --username $user --password-file $pathToPasswordFile
```

im getting the following message and a scoop job isnt being created

> --incremental lastmodified option for hive imports is not supported. Please remove the parameter --incremental lastmodified.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, see details in [SQOOP-2986](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SQOOP-2986)

Comment: Perhaps a little more explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

for some reason this flag was disabled on the platform